Wrong hex reading through serial port c#
I`m trying to read hex values through serialport from microcontroller in visual studio, and data that
higher than 126 index in ascii table is receiving like 3F which represents "?", or it reads just wrong data. Wrong data cames from library function at the beginning of the reading event.
I tryed every read function, readChar,ReadBytes,ReadExisting,Read but result is the same. I have no clue why doesn't this work. Will appreciate any help.
//Here is the code:
 string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
 cBoxCOMPORT.Items.AddRange(ports);

 btnOpen.Enabled = true;
 btnClose.Enabled = true;

 chBoxDtrEnable.Checked = false;
 serialPort1.DtrEnable = false;
 chBoxRTSEnable.Checked = false;
 serialPort1.RtsEnable = false;
 serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");

 private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         serialPort1.Read(byte_input, count-1, 1);

         count--;

         string hexValue = byte_input[count].ToString("X2");
         this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(hexValue + " ")));

         if (count == 0)
         {
             value = BitConverter.ToSingle(byte_input, 0);
             Array.Clear(byte_input, 0, byte_input.Length);
             this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
             count = 4;
         }


In your description you talk of characters "higher than 126 in ASCII table". ASCII is 7-bit, so spans the decimal values 0-127 (only). Perhaps you mean Windows-1252, which you specify in the code, but are you sure that's the correct encoding? Have you tried others?

Yes, I tryed all basic encodings like utf8, unicode and etc. But does encoding even matters when we are trying to read raw byte from buffer? I said about ASCII because I noticed that, wrong data occurs only with hex values above decimal 127, that representing characters in Extended ASCII (like 128-0x80-€).

I don't understand the problem .... do you mean you receive the value right, but the problem is encoding it in Text Box OR you receive the value wrong From the microcontroller ... add the microcontroller code to make us understand what you try to send and what you received in your program

I receive the wrong hex value, for example, I send 0x80, Serial.Read() returns 0x3F

I Have Test Your Method, and it Works Just Fine.

Maybe your controller code has a problem because your code work just fine and here some values send over the port received with same code you have

Check serialPort1.DataBits…

It looks fine. 8 bits as needed
